# Warning: compiled but with compilation errors oracle compile pl/sql error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi im new here and also new to oracle pl/sql blocks this is the code on compiling it return Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

```
 create or replace function func_o12 return varchar2
       is
         declare nn varchar2(20);
     begin
        select
              case substr(1234,1,3)
                  when '134' then '1234 is a match'
                  when '1235' then '1235 is a match'
                  when concat('1','23') then concat('1','23')||' is a match'
              else 'no match'
              end
         into :nn  
           from dual;
       return :nn;
      end;
```

Comment: You don't need to use a query in this case - just assign `nn` directly, e.g. `nn := case ... end;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the declare or the bind markers:

```
create or replace function func_o12 return varchar2
       is
         nn varchar2(20);
     begin
        select
              case substr(1234,1,3)
                  when '134' then '1234 is a match'
                  when '1235' then '1235 is a match'
                  when concat('1','23') then concat('1','23')||' is a match'
              else 'no match'
              end
         into nn  
           from dual;
       return nn;
      end;
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Kite in which scenario below query will run using :w_date because this query syntax correct but i dont know in which scenario query will run successfully?
select a.* from  hr.employees a where to_char(a.hire_date,'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss')  =:w_date;

Comment: I doubt you want to specify hh:mm:ss for a hire date, maybe like this:
`:w_date := '2014/01/16';`
`select a.* from hr.employees a where to_char(a.hire_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') = :w_date;`

Comment: im asking about the variable :w_date specially the sign :  ? if i want an Substitution in a query like where employee_id=:hereicanSubstite; the variable but i want this using sign :variablename i have a alternative for this which is & sign Substitution.

Comment: The : indicates it is a bind variable, which is a kind of substitution. It's the right thing to use for the situation you're describing. I don't believe & substitution is available outside of SQL*Plus.